# add class in master page(code behind) using child page in asp and c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a page and I am using code behind to show active tab cause the tabs are on my master page and contents on child page.

But I don't know why it's not working I used it in many application in that all its working fine but not in this particular .

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl currdiv = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)Master.FindControl("ClientTab");
currdiv.Attributes.Add("class", "ClientTabActive");
```

Please checkout my code and give me suggestion why it's not working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: @soner Gonul , just try to understand the things before your votes .... not working means not giving desire output .... i donno why you people do this type of activities

Comment: @AshwaniPandey I wasn't.

Comment: sorry but i doono why people do this type activities i know i am newbie thats why i asked this ques.

Comment: Can we see your markup ?

Comment: <li><a href="Clients.aspx">
                            <div id="ClientTab" class="MainNavigationContainerItem">
                                Client</div>
                        </a></li>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FindControl` is only able to find server-side controls, not plain HTML tags. In your case it means that you should add attribute `runat="server"` to the `ClientTab` div:

```
<li>
    <a href="Clients.aspx">
        <div id="ClientTab" class="MainNavigationContainerItem" runat="server"> Client</div>
    </a>
</li>
```

However your code seems to add yet another `class` tag to this control, which might not be what you are looking for. Most likely what you want to have is

```
class="MainNavigationContainerItem ClientTabActive"
```

in which case the second line of your code-behind should look like this:

```
currdiv.Attributes["class"] = string.Format("{0} {1}", currdiv.Attributes["class"], "ClientTabActive";
```